# error when creating a react project npm errno -4058

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying to create a new project on react, but this error is constantly being issued. I checked the whole Internet, but I didn't find a solution to the problem.

```
PS C:\react> npx create-react-app newProject
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
npm ERR! path C:\react
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn bash ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\LK\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-06T15_31_58_125Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the cache, after I entered it into the console, the problem was solved.

```
npm config set cache C:\tmp\nodejs\npm-cache --global
```